# Retain $_SESSION while working with IFRAMEs

Tags: php, session, iframe

I have googled this extensively and am still not sure I fully understand the answer.

Is it possible to retain `$_SESSION` variables throughout several calls of a .php file from the same server into an iframe? The .php file gets called by way of POST form submission and gets opened inside an iframe.

The .php file ALSO needs to share the same $_SESSION variables.

The general idea is this - unless a user is logged in (`$_SESSION['userLoggedIn']` and `$_SESSION['userName']`, the user should neither see the interface HTML, nor the .php file in the iframe.

Right now, as soon as I post the form into the php file in the iframe, the session is lost. And so I get the authorization login inside the iframe.

2 questions:

1. Can this be worked out with IFRAMEs?
2. If not, what is the best way to deal with it?

Answer (score 1):

Yes it can be worked within iframes if they're within the same domain. Make sure you do a `session_start()` on the `iframe` pages.

Comment: i have `session_start()` on every page, but still the session gets lost as soon as I submit the form that refreshes the iframe

Comment: is your form posting to an iframe? or is it being loaded on the iframe and being posted there itself?

Comment: form sits in a main doc with an initiated session. There is a javascript link in the main doc that processes the contents of the textarea, sets `myform.action=page.php`; `myform.target=`iframename`; and runs `myform.submit()`. Page.php also has session_start() immediately following `<?php` but whenever I press the link to populate the iframe with page.php, the session variables that made it to the main doc are lost.

Comment: Do you set the `$_SESSION` variables after the iframe has started, i.e it's `session_start()` has been called? If so the changes will only be visible after a browser refresh

Comment: session variables are set only on the logon stage, in a different file. basically, every other page has a check on top of the file to the effect that if session variables are not set properly then the pages shoots out a `header('Location: login.php');`